# Don't understand how to use changlistener in JavaFX

Tags: resize, listener, javafx, scene

I am trying to add a changlistener to Scene.getWidth() so I can detect a resize. This is a code snipplet of how I tried to add the listener.

```
scene.getWidth().addListener(new ChangeListener<Double>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Double> ov,double old_val, double new_val) {
        System.out.println(new_val);
    }
});
```

It gives me the followig errors.

> ./GraphFX.java:49: error:  is not abstract and
>   does not override abstract method changed(ObservableValue,Double,Double) in ChangeListener
>         scene.getWidth().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
>
> ^ 
> ./GraphFX.java:49: error: double cannot be dereferenced
>         scene.getWidth().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
>                         ^ 2 errors

Answer (score 2):

scene.getWidth() returns a double primitive not an object thats why it cannot be dereferenced    .`public final double getWidth()`

you can use scene widthProperty() method which returns ReadOnlyDoubleProperty

```
 scene.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, Object t, Object t1) {
         double value = (double) t1;
            System.out.println("Scene Width :" + value);
        }

   });
```

alternatively you can track scenewidth changes by just binding scene widthproperty

code :

```
DoubleProperty sceneWidth = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
sceneWidth.bind(scene.widthProperty());
```

Comment: So how would I go about binding the width of a rectangle to the widthProperty of Scene?

Comment: rectangle.widthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());